# What is a magic function in C/C++ (in regards to OpenMP)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, openmp, icc

Currently looking at [this](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/) guide to using OpenMP with C/C++ programs and wonder what they mean by `creating a magic function` in the quote below:

> Internally, GCC implements this by creating a magic function and
>   moving the associated code into that function, so that all the
>   variables declared within that block become local variables of that
>   function (and thus, locals to each thread). ICC, on the other hand,
>   uses a mechanism resembling fork(), and does not create a magic
>   function. Both implementations are, of course, valid, and semantically
>   identical.

Comment: The guide is not correct. ICC also performs function outlining the same way GCC does. The Intel OpenMP runtime even contains a GCC compatibility layer and can be used with programs compiled with GCC. The PGI compiler is the one that doesn't.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18789429/1374437) for some insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "magic" function is a function created by the compiler - its magicness comes from the fact that you as a programmer don't need to do anything, it's "magically done for you".