# How to print local variables of an OpenMP parallel region in gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, openmp

I'm stuck with debugging local variables inside an OpenMP parallel region.

Taking this code in consideration:

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(a)
    {
    int m_a = a + omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("%d\n",m_a); //breakpoint set here
    }
}
```

The code runs well, but if I set a breakpoint at the line with the comment and type `info locals` on gdb, it just shows the `a` variable. Typing `print m_a` results on `No symbol "m_a" in current context.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using GDB with OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768674/using-gdb-with-openmp)

Comment: Similar, but not the same case: in that problem the user could not see shared variables inside parallel region. In my case, I can (`a` is a shared variable).

Comment: @648trindae: Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers nothing, just report that I cannot repeat it, the code is compiled with

```
gcc x.c -W -Wall -fopenmp -ggdb
```

and gdb session as the following, everything seems fine, I guess it may be related with compile flag, try add -O0 in addition to -g or -ggdb

```
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) break 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40064d: file x.c, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /some/path/to/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Thread 3 "a.out" hit Breakpoint 1, main._omp_fn.0 () at x.c:9
9           printf("%d\n",m_a); //breakpoint set here
(gdb) info locals
m_a = 2
a = 0
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  1    Thread 0x2aaaaaaebb40 (LWP 31287) "a.out" main._omp_fn.0 () at x.c:9
  2    Thread 0x2aaaabab0700 (LWP 31516) "a.out" main._omp_fn.0 () at x.c:9
* 3    Thread 0x2aaaabcb1700 (LWP 31517) "a.out" main._omp_fn.0 () at x.c:9
  4    Thread 0x2aaaabeb2700 (LWP 31518) "a.out" main._omp_fn.0 () at x.c:9
(gdb) thread 1
[Switching to thread 1 (Thread 0x2aaaaaaebb40 (LWP 31287))]
#0  main._omp_fn.0 () at x.c:9
9           printf("%d\n",m_a); //breakpoint set here
(gdb) info locals
m_a = 0
a = 0
(gdb) thread 2
[Switching to thread 2 (Thread 0x2aaaabab0700 (LWP 31516))]
#0  main._omp_fn.0 () at x.c:9
9           printf("%d\n",m_a); //breakpoint set here
(gdb) info locals
m_a = 1
a = 0
(gdb)
```